# 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'train_on_batch'

Tags: keras

how do i solve this error or what can i use instead:
'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'train_on_batch'

trying to build a VEA-GAN

```
encImg = G.predict(latent_vect)
fakeImg = G.predict(noise)
DlossTrue = D_true.train_on_batch(dataset, np.ones((batch_size, 1)))
DlossEnc = D_fromGen.train_on_batch(encImg, np.ones((batch_size, 1)))
DlossFake = D_fake.train_on_batch(fakeImg, np.zeros((batch_size, 1)))
```

Comment: only Model instances have that function, why are you calling them in plain tensors?

Comment: because i am lazy a try to copy this one and use it on my data:  https://github.com/crmaximo/VAEGAN/blob/467c32505cbef7d44e25e58653f8e3ffc8122c66/VAEGAN.py